# SQL Update Statement Where Value Must Be Greater Than the Previous Value But less Than the next

Tags: sql, sql-server

Did know what would be an appropriate title for this question.
I've been struggling with this for a while.
I have two tables.
Table 1: Holds records of object ids, an email date and a response flag
Table 2: Holds records of object ids and a response date.

I need to update Table 1's response flag but because there are multiple records for the same object id in each table the response date from table 2 would have to be greater than the previous email date but less than the next email date from table 2.

Desired results

[image]

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.
Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a join. We'll simply look for the row in Table2 that matches our ObjectId and has the smallest ResponseDate that is > our EmailDate using rows who have the largest EmailDate that is < our ResponseDate.

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.ResponseFlag = (CASE WHEN t2.ObjectId IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.ObjectId = t1.ObjectId AND
                       t1.EmailDate = (SELECT MAX(EmailDate) FROM Table1
                                       WHERE ObjectId = t1.ObjectId AND EmailDate < t2.ResponseDate) AND
                       t2.ResponseDate = (SELECT MIN(ResponseDate) FROM Table2
                                          WHERE ObjectId = t1.ObjectId AND ResponseDate > t1.EmailDate)
```